# How can I get intellisense for an object called with an unknown variable?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord.js, intellisense, jsdoc

i'm developing a discord.js bot and I have an object (called `dtm`) that keeps all users' data.
It has this structure:

```js
{
// id of the user : {data}
"92875891383" : {wallet: 100}
}
```

If in the code I use `dtm[interaction.user.id]` I don't get intellisense for the user's parameters, I think because intellisense doesn't know what `interaction.user.id` is. How can I achieve this? I thought with JSDoc, but i don't know quite how to achieve this...

Comment: Just look into the [jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/) documentation. It goes through everything you can do with it, and how it works. You are correct that JSDoc can be used to do what you are trying to do, but it's probably best if you look through the documentation yourself and learn how to do this properly as opposed to getting someone to do it for you on StackOverflow. You will probably need to use jsdoc to document both `interaction.user.id` and the structure of your `dtm` object.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I used this JSDoc:

```
/**
 *
 * @returns {{[key: string] : theSchema}} playerData 
*/
```

And it finally worked! Thank you